# Angular to .net core web api. Getting rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a function

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to get a list of records from my .net core web api which is hosted on my local IIS. I followed the tutorial on how to do this. I got this to work and display with the following code which calls a json test website.

```
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Next, I want to switch the URL to my local.

```
 getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/api/account')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I am not sure why the angular page will display content from the json test site versus my local iis. When I tested the webapi it works with postman and chrome url.

I also added the import 'rxjs/add/Observable/throw' but throwing the same error.

Why does it work with the json feed from the test site but not my web api. That is my confusion and how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Which I hit f12, I see the following errors

> core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError:
>   rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a
>   function
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../src/app/services/user.service.ts.UserService.handleError
>   [as selector] (user.service.ts:38)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error
>   (catchError.js:34)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:83)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:61)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onError (http.js:1066)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:496)

user.service.ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/api/account')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Here is my user component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/throw'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage: string;
  users$; Object;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    // need to subscriber to the Observable method to get data
     this.users$ = this.userService.getUsers()
         .subscribe(( userData )=> this.users$ = userData );
  }

}
```

Comment: Add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'` to the component's import statements. If you expect to throw observable errors from more than one component, you can add it to the `app.module` imports instead.

Comment: this is a compilation error, so it's Typescript type-checking. Kind of hard to see without having the `handleError` function typed out...but most likely it's a closure issue where `this` contextually means `Observable` and not your component. Try passing a lexical `this` with a fat arrow: `.catch(err => this.handleError(err))`